# relationships and MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

okay so I have a teams table with `TeamID, TeamName` and a games table with columns `gameid, team1, team2`.

Now I dont have team1 and team2 as Foreign keys to the teams table. I understand this will make it easier but I want to learn without doing that. So `team1`, and `team2` are int fields. There is no constraint check.

So when I display it in my view, it displays the team1 and team2 columns but instead of displaying the integer ID, I want it to pull the team name from the teams table.

okay in my view I have the following:

```
   @model IEnumerable<Betting.Models.Bets>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of Games";
}
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "EndDate", rowsPerPage: 3);    
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<h2>
    Betting List</h2>
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Subject"),
            grid.Column("Team1"),
            grid.Column("Team2")          
        )
    )
</div>
```

And my controller is really simple:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{

    return View(db.Bets.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use view models in ASP.NET MVC and you won't have such problems:

```
public class TeamViewModel
{
    public string Team1Name { get; set; }
    public string Team2Name { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

then in the controller action do the necessary mapping/querying in order to populate this view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Fetch the data here, depending on the ORM you are using
    // perform the necessary joins so that you have the team names
    IEnumerable<Betting.Models.Bets> model = ...

    // map the model to the view model previously defined
    IEnumerable<TeamViewModel> viewModel = ...

    // pass the view model to the view for display
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

finally in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TeamViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of Games";
}
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "EndDate", rowsPerPage: 3);    
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<h2>Betting List</h2>
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Subject"),
            grid.Column("Team1Name"),
            grid.Column("Team2Name")          
        )
    )
</div>
```

As far as the mapping between your models and view models is concerned [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could greatly simplify this task.